# How to use TMC2209 driver to stop print when an obstruction is hit in Marlin

Tags: marlin, stepper-driver, safety, tmc2209

I have built a big gantry (1 m x 1 m) and currently use TMC2208 drivers and Marlin on a RAMPS 1.4 board. When working at high speeds, this could get dangerous if someone gets their hand in the way or something. According to the Marlin documentation

> Some TMC stepper drivers (e.g. TMC2209s) can detect when they bump into something that causes them to stop moving. This feature is so sensitive that it can actually take the place of traditional endstops.

How can I use this feature of TMC2209s to stop the print if it bumps into something as a kind of safety feature?

Comment: It depends on the TMC2209's you have bought, if stand-alone you cannot use senserless homing. Please let us know what stepper drivers you bought.

Comment: I haven't bought any yet. I was simply researching into the possibility of stopping the print if the machine bumps into something at any time. Sensor-less homing would simply be a bonus thrown in.

Comment: Sensor-less homing is the functionality you are after. Current Prusa i3's will reset (and thus home) when movement is restricted by the print head (your definition of a bump can be handling or a print defect for instance) and resume printing. So sensorless homing is not the bonus, it is part of the functionality you are requesting.

Comment: I'm having the same question, but I think its not just about (sensorless) homing. I also would like to stop the movement if we bump into an object. Is there a way to achieve this?  
Preferably, the solution should work both in StealthChop and SpreadCycle mode.

I read about M914: https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M914.html
Would that work?